# How to update column in one table from another if both tables have a text field in common

Tags: mysql

I have two tables Token and distinctToken. Following is the description of the two tables.

**Token**
(id int, text varchar(100), utokenid int)

**distinctToken**
(id int, text varchar(100))

The text field in both tables have same data with one exception, that is text field in Token table contains repeated entries.

I wanted to update the Token table such that the utokenid it becomes a foreign key. To be more specific i want to set the value of **Token.utokenid = distinctToken.id** where **Token.text is the same as distinctToken.text**. Is it possible using update or should i write a stored procedure to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Token t, distinctToken dt SET t.utokenid = dt.id WHERE t.text = dt.text;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are 100% right and missing nothing, I was missing patience as I terminated after 10 minutes each time I ran the same query, mysql took 31 minutes to execute the update. Thank you

Comment: You can help that by first adding an index to both columns. You can then drop the index after you're done, if needed.