# How to copy columns data to another table with common column data exist on the both tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy data of two columns into another table which have many columns and there is a common column on the both tables.

Here is my tables:

1. Table1

### ID  |   col1    |   col2

### 1   |   13  |   12

### 2   |   8   |   3

### 3   |   7   |   10

2. Table2

   ### ID  |   col1    |   col2    |   col3    |   col4

### 1   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0

### 2   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0

### 3   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0

i tried to used this UPDATE query from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268531/how-to-update-column-in-one-table-from-another-if-both-tables-have-a-text-field)

```
UPDATE table2 a,table1 b SET 
a.col1 = b.col1,
a.col2 = b.col2,
a.col3 = a.col3 + b.col1,
a.col4 = a.col4 + b.col2
WHERE a.ID = b.ID
```

but it gives

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
```

Anyway is it possible to do that ?
sorry if i didn't managed to write tables with a nice way but it seems stackoverflow doesn't create tables.

Comment: mysql or sql-server ? you tagged both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax looks correct for MySQL, but is better written as:

```
UPDATE table2 a join
       table1 b
       on a.ID = b.ID
    SET a.col1 = b.col1,
        a.col2 = b.col2,
        a.col3 = a.col3 + b.col1,
        a.col4 = a.col4 + b.col2;
```

For SQL Server, the syntax is:

```
UPDATE a
    SET col1 = b.col1,
        col2 = b.col2,
        col3 = a.col3 + b.col1,
        col4 = a.col4 + b.col2
    FROM table2 a join
         table1 b
         on a.ID = b.ID;
```

The error in SQL Server could have been on the alias after the table or on the `a` in the `set` statements.